# What does this Swift code do: var greetingDidChange: ((GreetingViewModelProtocol) -> ())?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, protocols

I've done a lot of research on this so I'll tell you what I sort of think it does and then **hopefully someone can tell me what it actually does**.

I'm trying to understand the MVVM pattern by learning from a tutorial ([link](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-architecture-patterns-ecba4c38de52#.3p1kc2gov)). I'll put all the code here in case anybody wants to drop it into Xcode.

My view model is called GreetingViewModel which adopts a protocol and contains this line of code I don't understand:

```
protocol GreetingViewModelProtocol: class {      
  var greeting: String? { get }
  var greetingDidChange: ((GreetingViewModelProtocol) -> ())? { get set }
  init(person: Person)
  func showGreeting()
}

class GreetingViewModel : GreetingViewModelProtocol {
  let person: Person
  var greeting: String? {
    didSet {
      self.greetingDidChange?(self)
    }
  }

  // what does line do???
  var greetingDidChange: ((GreetingViewModelProtocol) -> ())?

  required init(person: Person) {
    self.person = person
  }

  @objc func showGreeting() {
    self.greeting = "Hello" + " " + self.person.firstName + " " + self.person.lastName
  }
}
```

In the view controller (below), when `self.viewModel = viewModel` executes, this runs the code in the property observer of `var viewModel`. That then assigns the function `(GreetingViewModelProtocol) -> ()` to `var greetingDidChange`.

```
class GreetingViewController : UIViewController {
  let showGreetingButton = UIButton()
  @IBOutlet weak var greetingLabel: UILabel!

  var viewModel: GreetingViewModelProtocol! {
    didSet {
      self.viewModel.greetingDidChange = { [unowned self] viewModel in
        self.greetingLabel.text = viewModel.greeting
      }
    }
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let model = Person(firstName: "David", lastName: "Blaine")

    let viewModel = GreetingViewModel(person: model)

    self.viewModel = viewModel

    showGreetingButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    showGreetingButton.tintColor = UIColor.black
    showGreetingButton.setTitle("Show Greeting", for: .normal)
    showGreetingButton.addTarget(self.viewModel, action: #selector(GreetingViewModel.showGreeting), for: .touchUpInside)

    showGreetingButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false    
    view.addSubview(showGreetingButton)
    let buttonTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: showGreetingButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.greaterThanOrEqual, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.topMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20)
    let buttonLeading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: showGreetingButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    showGreetingButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 2, 2, 2)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([buttonTop, buttonLeading])
  }
}
```

At this point, I believe this just means greetingDidChange holds a function that accepts any class object that adopts the `GreetingViewModelProtocol` protocol and returns nothing. The UI finishes loading and looks like this:

[image]

When I click on the Show Greeting button, `GreetingViewModel.showGreeting()` is called then the property observer on `var greeting` is executed (`self.greetingDidChange?(self)`) sending `GreetingViewModel` to this mysterious line of code I don't understand.

That causes this property observer to execute:

```
  var viewModel: GreetingViewModelProtocol! {
    didSet {
      self.viewModel.greetingDidChange = { [unowned self] viewModel in
        self.greetingLabel.text = viewModel.greeting
      }
    }
  }
```

Then the rest of the code executes and the message is displayed:

[image]

I think that because the `viewModel` is `GreetingViewModel`, that closure in the `var viewModel` property observer is setting `self.greetingLabel.text = GreetingViewModel.greeting`. There seems to be some kind of relationship between my mystery line of code `var greetingDidChange: ((GreetingViewModelProtocol) -> ())?` and the code in `viewModel.didSet`, but it beats me how it works.

**Am I even close and would someone be kind enough to explain to me what's going on here?**

Also, my simple model is:

```
struct Person {
  let firstName: String
  let lastName: String
}
```

Comment: That line simply declares a variable to hold the closure that will be executed when the model property changes. The type of the variable is a closure that accepts a reference to an object that implements `GreetingViewModelProtocol`

Comment: Hi Paul, I guess what I don't understand then is what that closure actually does. It accepts the object, but then what?

Comment: In your case it does `self.greetingLabel.text = viewModel.greeting`  That variable holds the closure, the closure is provided by the view in order to execute some code when the model is updated.  To my mind this is why MVVM isn't worth the effort on Cocoa.  It came from Windows where controls support data binding and all of this is done for you. With data binding support in the controls, multiple controls could bind to the same viewmodel property.  Here you are limited to 1 observer block

Comment: I think I get it. So `self.greetingDidChange?(self)` executes during the first load, that calls `var greetingDidChange` and the closure is assigned. But when `var greeting` changes again and self.greetingDidChange executes, it doesn't go to `var greetingDidChange` again because the closure is already assigned. It just executes the closure. Do I have that right? And I hear what you're saying about MVVM. I'm giving it a try on my small app to see if it's a direction I might want to go.

Comment: Also, Paul, if you'll make your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.